# python: finding smallest distance between two points in two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, distance

I've got two lists containing a series of tuples (x,y), representing different points on a Cartesian plane:

```
a = [(0, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
b = [(3, 4), (4, 1), (5, 3)]
```

I'd like to find the two points (one for each list, not within the same list) at the smaller distance, in this specific case:

```
[((2, 4), (3, 4))]
```

whose distance is equal to 1. I was using list comprehension, as:

```
[(Pa, Pb) for Pa in a for Pb in b \
if math.sqrt(math.pow(Pa[0]-Pb[0],2) + math.pow(Pa[1]-Pb[1],2)) <= 2.0]
```

but this uses a threshold value. Is there a way to append an `argmin()` somewhere or something like that and get only the pair `[((xa, ya), (xb, yb))]` smallest distance? Thanks.

Comment: You can create dictionary of pair and distance between them ...then u can select pair having min dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy
e = [(Pa, Pb) for Pa in a for Pb in b]
e[numpy.argmin([math.sqrt(math.pow(Pa[0]-Pb[0],2) + math.pow(Pa[1]-Pb[1],2)) for (Pa, Pb) in e])]
```

Will use argmin as you suggested and return ((2, 4), (3, 4))

Comment: `NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined`, fix it by calling `np.argmin`

Comment: No problem urgeo, happy to help :) Feel free to accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use list comprehension and min as follows:

```
dist = [(Pa, Pb, math.sqrt(math.pow(Pa[0]-Pb[0],2) + math.pow(Pa[1]-Pb[1],2)))
        for Pa in a for Pb in b]

print min(dist, key=lambda x:x[2])[0:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution similar to DevShark's one with a few optimization tricks:

```
import math
import itertools
import numpy as np

def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.hypot(p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1])

a = [(0, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
b = [(3, 4), (4, 1), (5, 3)]

points = [tup for tup in itertools.product(a, b)]

print(points[np.argmin([distance(Pa, Pb) for (Pa, Pb) in points])])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the scipy.spatial library with the following :

```
import scipy.spatial as spspat
import numpy as np
distanceMatrix = spspat.distance_matrix(a,b)
args = np.argwhere(distanceMatrix==distanceMatrix.min())
print(args)
```

This will return you the following : `array([[3, 0]])` , being the position of the points in each list. 
This should also work in any dimension.